# Why does this EasyMock test fails?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, easymock

Hi I have this test below failing and giving me this error, the fail is on the Verify... but I can't get why.

> java.lang.AssertionError: 
>   Expectation failure on verify:
>      debug(isA(java.lang.Object)): expected: 1, actual: 0

The test code is this.

```
   public void testLogInfo()
   {
      JDBCAppender jdbcAppender = createNiceMock(JDBCAppender.class);
      Logger logger = createNiceMock(Logger.class);
      LogDB logDB = new LogDB(null, null, null, LogDBDriver.ODBC, Level.TRACE);
      logDB.setJdbcAppender(jdbcAppender);
      logDB.setLogger(logger);
      // method call
      logger.info(isA(Object.class));      
      expectLastCall().once();
      // replay
      replay(logger);
      replay(jdbcAppender);
      // verify method call
      logDB.log(Level.INFO, "10", "Server", "admin", "shortext", "longText","className","methodName");
      verify(logger);
   }
```

Comment: Seems like there's an expected but unfulfilled debug() invocation. Does the LogDB do any debug logging in any of the setters, in addition to the info log you originally want to test?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question... LogDB is responsible for inserting it into a Database, but as this is a mock there is no DB data in the LogDB constructor call as you can see above, could this be the problem ?

Comment: LogDB is the class under test. jdbcAppender and logger are mocks, and these are set to the logDB instance. My question was, does the LogDB class call logger.debug() in the setLogger method? If the error message really says what I think it says, namely that logger.debug() was invoked before calling replay(logger), then logDB.setLogger seems to be the only place where logger.debug() could be be invoked.

Comment: Got your point, but the setLogger is only a simple setter method this.x = x; But I will look for a call like that somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out what was wrong.

The method call LogDB.log was not calling Logger.info(Object) it was callig Logger.log(Priority, Object).

That's why after the replay, the state was not the same, as it was expecting one kind of call and receiving another.

Comment: Then why does the error state that a call to `debug()` is missing, when `logger.info()` is invoked in the test case?